# How to give a custom width to a C console application for windows

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, console, window

I am working on a C console application. For text spacing and formatting purposes, I need wider window than what it currently is when the program builds.

Is it possible to set a custom width for the console window when it runs?

Comment: Use SetConsoleScreenBufferSize() to make the screen buffer large enough first.  Then you can call SetConsoleWindowInfo() to resize and position the console window.  Boilerplate is that you *do* leave this up to the user.

Comment: Hey Hans, thanks for the reply. Where in my code do I add this? PS: I'm just starting out with C. So I'm unsure about a lot of things.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First thing in main() is an obvious place.  Do focus a bit on learning to program in C instead.